# When deploying java application using maven eclipse to Azure, servlet pages do not get deployed

Tags: java, azure, eclipse, servlets, azure-web-app-service

This is my first time trying to deploy an application to azure using eclipse. I am using pHp myadmin local database. I have not configured my database in azure yet. I am not sure if its needed. I am using apache tom cat server. It runs fine on apache tomcat including the servlet pages. I get issues when I deploy the application on Azure.

I tried to deploy my web application using the Azure toolkit plugin available in eclipse.
These are the exact steps I followed.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/publish-azure-web-app-with-azure-toolkit-eclipse/4-deploy-web-app-azure

Configuration
[image]

As you can see below non servlet pages are visible upon deployment
[image]

But the moment I go to a page with servlet they give me this error.
[image]

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue is greatly appreciated!

Edit: I managed to access logs in Azure
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Check the Tomcat logs for stack traces and the reason for the 500 error. Share them in the question.

Comment: @nitind By tomcat logs do you mean in azure or in eclipse?

Comment: The place where you're getting the 500 error--Azure.

Comment: You absolutely need to copy and paste the stack trace into the question as plain text instead of as screenshots. This way your question is Googleable for others facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The below are the things need to check to resolve the issue of servlet pages not being deployed to Azure.

1. Verify the required dependencies for your servlet pages are included in your pom.xml file.
2. Check the Azure logs for any error messages related to the deployment of your servlet pages.
3. Ensure that the database configuration in your application is correct and matches the configuration of your database in Azure.
4. Try redeploying your application after making any necessary changes to your database configuration.
5. Make sure that the Apache Tomcat server version you are using is compatible with Azure.
6. Ensure that the port on which your Apache Tomcat server is running is open in the firewall settings in Azure.

**Steps to deploy java application using maven eclipse to Azure:**

Creating a Java project in Eclipse, go to File > New > Java Project, enter a name for your project, and click Finish.
If Maven is not already configured in your Eclipse installation, and you need to install the Maven plugin. Go to Help > Eclipse Marketplace, search for "Maven", and select the Maven Integration for Eclipse plugin.

Click the Install button, accept the license agreement, and restart Eclipse when prompted.
Create a pom.xml file and Right-click on your Java project, go to New > Other, select Maven > Maven Project, and click Next. Select the project and enter your project information, such as groupId, artifactId, and version, and click Finish.

**Create a deployment package.**

In the pom.xml file, add the following build plugin to create a deployment package:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Build the deployment package by choosing Java project, go to Run As > Maven build, enter "package" in the Goals field, and click Run.
A jar file will be created in the target directory of your project.

Create an Azure App Service

Deploy the Java application to Azure In the Azure portal, go to the Deployment Center of your Azure App Service, select FTP, and click Continue. Download the publish profile, and then use an FTP client, such as FileZilla, to upload the jar file to the site/wwwroot/webapps directory.

Verify the deployment In the Azure portal, go to the URL of your Azure App Service, and verify that your Java application.

[image]

[image]

Reference taken from
[Java app on Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-java?tabs=javase&pivots=platform-linux-development-environment-maven)

[Deploy WebApps to Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/maven-deploy-java-web-apps-to-azure/)